# Do I have to create a customer billing agreement before I create a recurring payments profile(Paypal Integration)?

Tags: c#, soap, paypal

I am creating a social media pay site and need to create a recurring billing profile for each person that registers for the site.

I downloaded the soap API, as I would like to make the transactions seamless to the user and not display any paypal buttons, just have the transactions go through my interface.

I have several questions:-

1. Do I need to call the SetCustomerBillingAgreeement before I call the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile?
2. I do not see any place asking me to enter the customers address information, where do I enter the persons Billing information, name, address, city, state, zipcode, credit card information, etc?

I really need documentation detailing how to perform the necessary steps for creating, updating, and setting up a customer billing agreement.